# I have a project from another device and when i try to install in my device the error appears

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.8

If I do `composer install` this happens:

> PHP Warning:  Uncaught ErrorException:
>   require(C:\xampp\htdocs\multitech\taskmanagment\vendor\composer/../symfony/polyfill-php72/bootstrap.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or di
>       rectory in C:\xampp\htdocs\multitech\taskmanagment\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php:66
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\multitech\taskmanagment\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(66):
>   Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'require(C:\xamp...',
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 66, Array)

Answer (score 0):

Check your.htaccess file maybe you changed something in your code when you uploaded on a cpanel

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Also refer to this [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8)